# The use of ros navigation stack in dynamic environment

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I need to use the ROS navigation stack for the environment with moving objects. Does anybody know if this stack handles such condition? If not, is there any package for this purpose?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239749/the-use-of-ros-navigation-stack-in-dynamic-environment/) by [A.M Dynamics](https://answers.ros.org/users/20607/a.m-dynamics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2016-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [teb_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner) package has now support for dynamic obstacles based on a constant velocity model.

You can find two new tutorials on that topic in the [tutorials section](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2018-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0